# How to convert char* to char** in mfc++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I have a code like this the input of the main program

`char * argv[]` I am now trying to get the argument from the command line function

```
char *argv = GetCommandLine();
```

but I cannot pass this function as a parameter to

```
parseCommandLineArguments(argc, argv);
```

its giving me error `cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *' to 'char **'`
Can anybody help me out here please. Thank you.

It is basically the arguments for the `main function` of a console. I am trying to change it to `main function` without input parameters in `MFC dialogue based application`.

Comment: You cannot simply _'convert'_ `argv` to `char**`! You might need to split the line up into single 'words', have a look at `strtok()`

Comment: `char**` means a pointer to a pointer to a char*, but in this particular case it's an old Cism and it's expecting a pointer to an array of pointers, each of which is pointing to a null-terminated string representing a token in the command line.

Comment: See this graphic: http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC506195.png replace "pstr" with "argv" and it should relate to your problem.

Comment: @g-makulik Do _not_ use `strtok()`.  Ever.  (And of course, it's not powerful enough to parse a command line anyway.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exist the global variables `__argc` and `__argv`/`__wargv` that you can access, which should already have the data filled.

Comment: I'd guess the OP needs to use the result from `GetCommandLine()`, whatever this is.

Comment: Thank you. the GetCommandLine() also returns the same arguments as that of the main function so i was using it to get the arguments so i can call the function without parameters in the MFC application.

Answer (score 3):

First of its clear case of converting char* to char**.If you want just conversion then you should go through following code.

```
char **variableName=(char **) argv;
```

but according to me you have multiple argument in single char* so you first break char* into multiple string.

It basic rule is that,

char* : - used for single character string like,

```
char* MyOwn = "Hey There";
```

While char** used for multiple string.

```
char** multipleString;
multipleString= (char**)malloc( 3 * sizeof(char*) );        //allocating memory location..
multipleString[0] = "First";
multipleString[1] = "Second";
multipleString[2] = "Third";
```

Comment: You should alloc `multipleString`: `char* multipleString[3];`

Comment: Opps sorry Updated :)!!

Comment: My proposal would have done it. Introducing `malloc()` just complicates everything.

Answer (score 0):

Off hand, I would guess that `parseCommandLineArguments` is
expecting the standard `(int, char**)` that were passed to
`main`.  `GetCommandLine()` returns the raw command line, which
you'd have to parse.  There doesn't seem to be any need for it;
just call `parseCommandLineArguments` with the arguments you got
in `main`.

Answer (score -3):

try this

char *****variableName=(char *****) *argv;

Comment: no it is not working it gives an unexpected error if i try this command line